# Is it mandatory to have Inherited on the first line, in a constructor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Is it mandatory to have Inherited on the first line, in a constructor?
Can I have other code before 'Inherited'?

Example:

```
constructor TMyIniFile.Create(SectionName: string);                                          
VAR Path: string;
begin
 Path:= UserProfileFolder;  //initialize path here

 inherited Create(Path);

 //more code ..
end;
```

Comment: I've never tried. I think that there will no problem to use local variables before calling `inherited` but I think you can't use object's fields.

Comment: You can do this but it's usually a sign of a design flaw. It would only matter if you were calling a virtual method in the base constructor. And you should call virtual methods from constructors.

Comment: @David Shouldn't that read "should *not* call"?

Comment: A long time ago there was a bug in the `TThread` implementation, that required you to call `Inherited` last in the constructor in some circumstances. Don't do this as a habit even if it is possible, since it will confuse future maintainers.

Comment: @LURD: the bug you refer to is when the base constructor is called with `ACreateSuspended=False`, it would start running the thread immediately, such that `Execute()` could begin running before the constructor had finished initializing the `TThread` object. But that bug was fixed way way back in Delphi 6.

Comment: @UliGerhardt Sorry. Of course you are right. You should **not** call virtual methods in constructors.

Comment: Does it makes sense to call `inherited`at the end of overriden destroy methods in stead of at the beginning ?

Comment: @guido yes it does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the advantages of Delphi's object model (compared to the C++ object model) is the fact that you - as the programmer - can decide WHEN you call the inherited constructor. The code you display in your question is perfectly safe to run.

Also - you can use the instance fields without problem, ie.

```
CONSTRUCTOR TSomeClass.Create;
  BEGIN
    FSomeInstanceField:=123;
    INHERITED Create;
  END;
```

This will call the inherited constructor, which will have access to the modified value of the FSomeInstanceField variable.

Comment: Usually it's a sign if a designer flaw when you do this.

Comment: you could even leave the inherited out of the code, not that its a good idea off course. I have to agree with @DavidHeffernan on this